# Docker. Run software with license based on host id

Tags: java, docker, licensing

I am developing a new product implemented in Java that requires a license to run. The license validation is based on the server ID. If I run it directly in a linux server it is not a problem.

But, I would like to offer the option of running my software inside docker, but the problem is that I don't know how to get the host ID from the docker container. I don't want to use docker container ID, as the customer could require to recreate it (for instance for a software update), so I need to know the ID of the host server.

I thought about using the MAC address, but it requires to run the container with the "--net=host" option and due to security reasons I would like to avoid to use that option.

Comment: What do you mean by "server id"? And how would your java program determine that the host it is running on is "valid"?

Comment: Thanks @GhostCat. With "server id", I mean something that confirm that the host server is "unique", for instance, Mac address or something that check that the same license is not used in many servers. I want that the license is valid for a single server.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should step back and look into alternative approaches, for example this system that works with **two** components:

1. Your users have some sort of ID + private key which can be stored in the local file system
2. Your application reads that file from disk; and then contacts your "home server" to validate that this ID + key is actually "good", and if so, your application starts; otherwise it stops

Such a solution would even allow people to include the licence file into their docker images.

And for the record: any other solution that doesn't make your application talk to a central server might give you real headaches.

Comment: Thanks @GhostCat! I have been thinking about it. Finally I have found a possible good alternative. I think I am going to create a container with an API that just generates the host id and is started with --net=host option. So it will be able to generate the "unique" host ID. So, from the main container I will just call to this API to get the host ID and check if the license installed is valid for it. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

The same problem happens to me with Matlab license I solved it using freezing host id docker-compose or docker give you this good feature to the default set your host id

```
version: '3.7'
services:
flask:
  container_name: flask # Name can be anything
  restart: always
  build: ./xyz
  mac_address: 1c:45:c6:12:20:33
```

remember to see which host id added to your license of MatLab set that same up here.